# How to read pixel value from a file and display using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have a file with pixel values like this:

```
78 234 56 37
62 162 63 78
28 129 30 37
12 231 12 127
24 121 95 194
```

which indicate that a 4*5 monochrome pixels map. I've got to read it from a file and store the pixel values in a list.

Now my question is, what shall I do to display it?

I was doing it in WPF, and some of the file is large (more than 50M), so processing speed must also be considered. Is there a best practice dealing with this kind of work in .NET?

Comment: Gut reaction is to use a MemoryMappedFIle, which provides efficient random-access to the file contents.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I would think sequential access (a Stream) would be a better choice.

Comment: @Dan: For a 50M file? It depends on what OP needs to do, but if access to individual pixels is the crux then random access seems the key.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: perhaps our assumptions are different.  I assumed the op wanted to display all pixels.  But if the op just wants to display *some* of the pixels, then you are correct, an mmf would be better suited.

Comment: Probably better to ask OP :)  - OP, what exactly are you asking here? 1. How should I load/access the large file? 2. How do I show these bytes as a bitmap? Also, what exactly does "Monochrome pixels map" mean?

Comment: Until now, I only need to display the whole pixels, not part of them

Comment: @JerKimball 1.the pixels value have been stored in a list.Top to Bottom,Left to Right. And the width and height value is also stored.

Comment: @JerKimball 2.I just ask how to show them..."Monochrome pixels map" mean that the pictures is grayscale(pixel value from 0 to 255). A pixel is stored by one byte

Comment: Ok, so literally, you just have a big image that you need to put up on the screen?

Comment: @JerKimball I've have a file with a few pixel values. These was generated by another programs. I don't know if that is a image or not.The pixel values was splited by space and carrier return.I have tried to resolve the file and put them in a List and put other values(etc..Height and Width).(I don't know if it is a proper way to do it).And I need a good way to put them on the screen

Comment: Oh...so you don't know what the data is? Where'd these pixels come from? And it's actually a **text** file, not byte values...ok, gotcha.

Comment: @JerKimball It is generated by a program written by my workmates. That program just decompressed file format(etc a gif,png file) and write the ouptput to a text file.I'll do the next few steps(This seems a little weired, but it is the way to go.....).